# Event listener will straight away fire even the event is not executed

Tags: javascript

I want to know why when i execute this in html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<p class="click">
 click here
</p>

<script>
 p=document.querySelector(".click");
 p.addEventListener("onclick",alert("click sucess"))
</script>

</html>
```

the alert will appear straight away fire after I open the browser, but not on click . and how do I make it fire when I click it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are passing executable code as the callback, rather than a function reference. As soon as the JavaScript runtime gets to that line, it simply executes the code you've place there.

**[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** requires a reference to a function to call when the specified event occurs. So, you need to wrap your executable code in a function (as I'm showing below) or simply reference a function by name that is already defined.

Also, the event is `click`, not `onclick` (that's an event property).

```html
<p class="click">click here</p>

<script>
 p = document.querySelector(".click");
 p.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("click sucess") } );
  
  // Or, reference a pre-existing function:
  function secondHandler(){
    alert("Even more success!");
  }
  
 p.addEventListener("click", secondHandler);  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `addEventListener` needs to be a **function**.

The expression `alert("click sucess")` will **immediately** call the `alert` function (passing it an argument) and evaluate as **the return value** of that function.

It is equivalent to:

```
var a_value = alert("click sucess");
p.addEventListener("onclick", a_value);
```

You need to create a new function that calls alert with the desired arguments.

Additionally, you need to get the name of the event correct. It is *click*, not *onclick*.

```
var a_value = alert.bind(window, "click sucess");
p.addEventListener("click", a_value);
```